# Hard starting, poor idle and exhaust smell

Tags: engine

Are these symptoms associated with valve problems? If so, is it better to replace the heads or just replace the defective valves?

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be due to faulty timing, fuel supply or ignition. What does the exhaust smell of? They are all smelly.

Answer (score 0):

Much more likely is a fuel problem or an ignition problem.

Check your fuel pressure, fuel flow, fuel injectors, fuel filter, fuel pump, fuel tank before assuming it's the valves.

After that check your ignition wires, your ignition coil or coils, your spark plugs.

A common and easy to run test for valve issues is a compression test.  Get a tester and check.  A leak-down test can also help but you may need a mechanic to do that.

While some problem with your valves may cause such problems, there are many simpler issues that can cause these that are a lot less expensive to check and repair.

Comment: Agree, although , I might say running rich : unburned or partially burned fuel. Very common in carburetor days.

Comment: Use an OBD-II scanner to check for stored codes and the long term fuel trim values, as jwh20 says if it's running rich these will be negative